# Serve different app on particular subdomain in multi-tenant system

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, multi-tenant

I have built an flask app hosted in App Engine, have used wildcard subdomain mapping along with namespace support provided App Engine so that app will be served from any subdomain. Its all working fine.

Now, I want to make one of the subdomain, say admin.domain.com  to handle some admin related activities. All other subdomain points to normal app.

When un-registered user visits company.domain.com, it should be redirected to admin.domain.com where he will register, once done he will go back automatically to company.domain.com.

How to map a admin app to particular subdomain? Is there anyway to do it using Flask or App Engine? If not possible, how to handle this scenario?

This is the first time I am building such a app.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the semantics when you use the word 'app'.  In strict GAE sense, an apps are completely separate, each with its own billing and datastore etc.

If you strictly want to have the admin app as a separate app, you can't use the wildcard subdomain mapping.  You'd have to manually map each subdomain using the App Engine admin settings for mapping domains.  You can map the admin.domain.com to your admin app, and manually map your other subdomains to the normal app.

If you're just talking about separate admin functionality that runs in the same app, and you're not strictly set on using admin.domain.com, the best way is probably to use the new modules functionality and create your 'admin' as a separate module and use dispatch.yaml to route to it:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Otherwise, Flask/GAE doesn't really provide any built in mechanism for this.  You'd have to do something messy like check the URL in every request handler and act appropriately if it's admin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah..I wanted to avoid checking url in every request, looking for some built-in mechanism. I thought of doing same as you mentioned in second paragraph. I don't know about new module functionality, will look into it.

Comment: Actually, with dispatch.yaml you should be able to route admin.domain.com to your admin module, so it's probably the best way to go for you.

Comment: I was going through it, will try that. Thanks.